# How to remove one side of padding completely? Also, how do I center a banner with another image aligned left in the same table row?

Tags: html, css, alignment, row, padding

Thanks in advance for any help.

What I am trying to achieve:
Firstly, if you preview that code, you will see that due to the padding of the Header, the page requires dragging a tiny bit to the right. When I remove all of the padding, this is not a problem. With the padding, it is. I have tried making all padding 5px and the right padding 0px, but this did not solve the issue.

Secondly, with the Banner, I am trying to make it center with the table row, rather than with the remaining space in the table row. Right now, because there is already an image aligned to the left of the table row, the image which I want aligned to the center of the page is aligning with ONLY the available space, so it's over to the right a bit too much.

Here is the work I have done sofar, please keep in mind, that this is only day two or working on it, so it is clearly quite messy sofar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Blank</title>

<style type="text/css">

body{ 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#045FB4;
margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;
}

A:link {color: #808080;} 
A:visited {color: #808080;} 
A:hover {color: #990000;}

#formwrap {
font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
border-radius:15px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);  
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color:#08298A;
opacity:0.8;

}

#header {
font:15px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color:#FFF;
width:100%;
height:30px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color:#999;
opacity: 0.6;
text-align:left;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-right:0px;
line-height: 30px;

}

img:logo.png {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}

</style>



</head>

<body>

<table align="center" width="100%" height="100%">

<div id="header" align="center"> Welcome to Blank.
</div>

<tr>

<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding:10px" alt="This image cannot be displayed." align="left"/>
<div align="center" style="width:100%"> <img src="http://placehold.it/728x90" style="padding:14px" alt="This image cannot be displayed." align="center" style="clear:both" style="float:left"/> 
</div>

</tr>

<br />
<tr align="center">
<td align="center" height="100%"> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/160x40" padding="0px"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/160x40" padding="0px"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/160x40" padding="0px"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/160x40" padding="0px"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/160x40" padding="0px"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">

<td align="center" height="100%">
<br>
<br>
<div id="formwrap"> 
<br> Text test.

</div>
</td>

</tr>
</table>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand the problem now for the first issue. It's because the padding-left pushes the header over to the right. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I tried making the right padding -5px, but this did not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "width: 100%;" from your header to fix the scrolling issue

Add "position: absolute;" to the image you have floating on the left and your title image should center itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing the width:100% did fix the problem, I can't believe I missed that. As for the position: absolute, I have already tried that but it does not appear to work.

Comment: did you add the "position: absolute;" to the image floating on the left?  The title should center itself once that is removed from the flow of the page.

Comment: Is this right? 

<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding:10px" alt="This image cannot be displayed." align="left" style="position:absolute;"/>

If so- it doesn't appear to be working. I also tried adding it to the css of that image with the same luck.

Comment: Ahh... that's strange, I changed it from position:absolute to position: absolute (added a space) and it worked, I never realised there needed to be a space. Thanks a heap for the help.

Comment: No problem.  Have fun with stuff!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because boxes are, by default, set to size as `content-box`. This means it takes the `width`, and then adds on `padding`, adds on `border`.

100% means total width of the parent element in this case. Which it then adds your `padding` to.

You can change the `box-sizing` to instead of add `padding` and `border`, to subtract it from total `width`:

http://jsfiddle.net/7WZph/

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is definitely the closest to what I'm looking for. However, after trying to code it appears to remove the bottom-padding as well, which is intended to be there.

Comment: You have a fixed `height: 30px;` where the bottom padding is eating into it now, because of the `box-sizing`. You can simply add the amount of padding you're adding (`5px`) to the `height` so that it's the same as it was before :) http://jsfiddle.net/7WZph/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Removing the 100% width from the header solved the issue (I can't believe I missed it haha).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem remove width: 100%; from #header. The second problem is not quite clear to me. What exactly do you want to achieve?
It is vertically centered in the row.
Maybe you mean horizontally centered in the column, centered in respect to the "Text test" box?
Please elaborate.

Edit: For the centering.

Maybe you want this?

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100px" height="100px" style="padding:10px" alt="x" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/728x90" style="padding: 14px" alt="x" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, removing the 100% width did fix the problem, I still can't believe I missed that, I swore I tried it. As for the centering, what I am trying to achieve is having it centered horizontally in respect to the "Text test" box.